# Track clicks to play button in html5 video control area

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video that plays when the poster is clicked, and when the play button in the control bar is clicked. I need a tracking pixel to fire whenever the video is played. I wrapped the video in a div and added an onlick to the div that fires the pixel. It fires when the poster/video area is clicked. But even tho the div covers the controls, it does not fire when the control area is clicked. How can I catch clicks to the controls? Or better yet, determine when the video gets played and fire the pixel.

Here is the code:

```
<div onclick="obApi('track', 'Watch Video');">
<video controls="controls" style="width: 100%;" poster="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/t/2/assets/poster_fox.jpg" onclick="this.play();">
<source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/files/fw_fox.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video tag has many [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) you can listen to. One being `play` which will fire when the video is no longer paused. Here is an example of how you can listen to that event.

```js
let clicks = 0;
let video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video.addEventListener("play", obApi);

function obApi() {
  clicks++;
  console.log(`I've been played ${clicks} time/s`);
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls" style="width: 100%;" poster="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/t/2/assets/poster_fox.jpg" onclick="this.play();">
<source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/files/fw_fox.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this function in video tag

```
        <video
          onPlay={() => {
             console.log('Hi clicked on play button')
          }}
         >
        </video>
```